# Debugging JSX using browser / plugins

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to debug JSX files?

I am unable to see the .jsx files when I check the resources tab in either safari / chrome. Can we use a debugger ?

Comment: No, as the browser does execute javascript not jsx files. [There might be sourcemaps, though](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/833)

Comment: Related post - [How do I generate sourcemaps when using babel and webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30870830/465053)

Answer (score 11):

After you install the [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) 
open the devTool (f12)  and you can see:

1. A new react tab - use to inspecting the react elements (like the regular inspect).

[image]

2. In source tab (left panel) a new App list where u can see the JSX files and set break points in side your code.

[image]

**NOTE: it might be necessary to restart chrome to get it going**

Answer (score 4):

There is [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) which adds another tab to Developer Tools and allows debug React Components. You can see preview and read more about it in [React documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/01/02/react-chrome-developer-tools.html).

[Other browsers doesn't have support for React Debugger, yet](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/56).

Comment: The chrome extension react tab is missing

Comment: @Joti Are you sure extension is installed properly and you are opening devtools on app using React? Sometimes I had to refresh whole page with devtools open to have it recognise React app.

If your problem still persist, file an issue on Github.

Comment: I reinstall it and it's working - but I still cannot set break point, is there a way to debug the js code? or should I just call the js code from .js files?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using webpack, then you can provide `devtool` configuration inside `webpack.config.js`.

```
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map'
   // rest of the webpack configurations
}
```

It will maintain the original source-code. You can view this source code under source tab in browser developer tools. (If you are using chrome/firefox then in source tab you can press `Ctrl + P` to quickly search for the file you want to debug/analyze.)

More about webpack devtool [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Browserify & watchify with `-d` will help generate source map if you are using them to build source, then you can track which file results in the error.