# How do I generate sourcemaps when using babel and webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, babeljs, source-maps

I want to set up a config to generate sourcemaps. I'm running `webpack serve` from the command line, which compiles successfully. But I really need sourcemaps. This is my `webpack.config.js`.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    publicPath: '/assets/'
  },

  cache: true,
  debug: true,
  devtool: true,
  entry: [
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/components/main.js'
  ],

  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'styles': __dirname + '/src/styles',
      'mixins': __dirname + '/src/mixins',
      'components': __dirname + '/src/components/',
      'stores': __dirname + '/src/stores/',
      'actions': __dirname + '/src/actions/'
    }
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'jsxhint'
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.sass/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&indentedSyntax'
    }, {
      test: /\.scss/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css!sass'
    }, {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|woff|woff2)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
    }]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Looking though the docs hasn't really helped as I'm not sure what this problem is specific to.

Comment: FYI  dont add debug for version 2 , i got `The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.`

Comment: Related post - [what's the difference using eval and eval-source-map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51223916/465053)

Comment: where is the babel here used? Shouldn't this be "webpack" question only?

Answer (score 520, accepted):

In order to use source map, you should change [`devtool`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) option *value* from `true` to the *value* which available in [`this list`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/), for instance `source-map`

```
devtool: 'source-map'
```

> [`devtool`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/): `'source-map'` - A SourceMap is emitted.

Comment: I can confirm (webpack 3.5): `devtool` is enough. No need for any debug value.

Comment: Just would like to add that if you're using React, you should find the specific config for it (create-react-app).

Comment: Where does it actually output the file to?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper, Typically, the file is named `*.map`, so if your file is `main.js`, then the sourcemap is called `main.js.map`.  During development with webpack-dev-server, howerver, **no sourcemap file is created on the file system**, but it is **magically created in memory and sent to the browser using Hot Module reloading technology.**  I hope that helps. :-)

Answer (score 114):

Maybe someone else has this problem at one point. If you use the `UglifyJsPlugin` in `webpack 2` you need to explicitly specify the `sourceMap` flag. For example:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ sourceMap: true })
```

Comment: I had to also include `devtool: 'source-map'` for it to work

Comment: I had to include this in the css and sass loader options.

Comment: also solved problem in webpack 5, spent the whole day troubleshooting this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#sourcemap

Answer (score 44):

Minimal webpack config for jsx with sourcemaps:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: `./src/index.jsx` ,
  output: {
    path:  path.resolve(__dirname,"build"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Running it:

```
Jozsefs-MBP:react-webpack-babel joco$ webpack -d
Hash: c75d5fb365018ed3786b
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 3826ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    bundle.js   1.5 MB       0  [emitted]  main
bundle.js.map  1.72 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 221 hidden modules
Jozsefs-MBP:react-webpack-babel joco$
```

Answer (score 27):

**If optimizing for dev + production**, you could try something like this in your config:

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// in webpack.shared.config

{
  devtool: dev ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : 'source-map', 
}
```

[From the docs:](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool)

- devtool: **"eval-cheap-module-source-map"** offers SourceMaps that only maps lines (no column mappings) and are much faster
- devtool: **"source-map"** cannot cache SourceMaps for modules and need to regenerate complete SourceMap for the chunk. It’s something for production.

Another option is to return false for production with the assumption you do not need sourcemaps for production builds.

I am using webpack 2.1.0-beta.19

Comment: recent, pretty precise liste for build+rebuild performance is [here in the official docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool)

Comment: Where / how is the `dev` variable set?

Comment: in typical cases you might see `.env` files defined or mutations to `process.env`. this is just an example but it could look like this: `const dev = process.env.development === true`

Answer (score 14):

On Webpack 2 I tried all 12 devtool options. The following options link to the original file in the console and preserve line numbers. See the note below re: lines only.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool

**devtool best dev options**

```
                                build   rebuild      quality                       look
eval-source-map                 slow    pretty fast  original source               worst
inline-source-map               slow    slow         original source               medium
cheap-module-eval-source-map    medium  fast         original source (lines only)  worst
inline-cheap-module-source-map  medium  pretty slow  original source (lines only)  best
```

**lines only**

Source Maps are simplified to a single mapping per line.
This usually means a single mapping per statement (assuming you author is this way).
This prevents you from debugging execution on statement level and from settings breakpoints on columns of a line.
Combining with minimizing is not possible as minimizers usually only emit a single line.

REVISITING THIS

On a large project I find ... eval-source-map rebuild time is ~3.5s ... inline-source-map rebuild time is ~7s

Answer (score 2):

Even same issue I faced, in browser it was showing compiled code. I have made below changes in webpack config file and it is working fine now.

```
 devtool: '#inline-source-map',
 debug: true,
```

and in loaders I kept babel-loader as first option

```
loaders: [
  {
    loader: "babel-loader",
    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")]
  },
  { test: /\.js$/, exclude: [/app\/lib/, /node_modules/], loader: 'ng-annotate!babel' },
  { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loaders: [
      'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
      'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
    ]
  },
  {test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less"},
  { test: /\.styl$/, loader: 'style!css!stylus' },
  { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' }
]
```

Comment: The `debug` property has been removed in webpack 2.

Comment: +1. Adding the `include` option is what fixed it for me. In webpack 2 it looks like this: `rules: [{loader: 'babel-loader', include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src")]`