# how to debug issue javascript file in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I download this example https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed .I am using webstrom editor and then use **npm install** then I use **npm start**..Apllication is running fine but I am not able to debug the app ..how I will debug the app?
is there any way to debug the app

I follow all steps

```
Clone or fork this repository
Make sure you have node.js installed
run npm install to install dependencies
run npm start to fire up dev server
open browser to http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: Where do you want to debug? Which IDE? In the browser just open the devtools and set a breakpoint. In WebStorm you might be able to just set a breakpoint before or while you're running the application. Please provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Anctually it minified all files

Comment: You might need to disable minification. You might need to enable source maps in the browser devtools settings (I don't use TS myself and don't know details)

Comment: I need debug at chrome..

Comment: Ya but i am not able to seacrh where i comment the code

Answer (score 2):

The webpack configuration on in this angular2 seed application is not configured to use sourcemaps. Have a look here: [How do I generate sourcemaps when using babel and webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870830/how-do-i-generate-sourcemaps-when-using-babel-and-webpack) for some hints

In short: 
In your tsconf.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true //Set to true to get source maps from .ts, not .js
  },
  "files": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

In your webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map', // to generate sourcemaps
```

Comment: If you restart the webpack server, you will get sourcemaps. -But I see this solution gives you sourcemaps for your compiled .ts files, not the actual source.

Comment: actually please download the code then you find it not working

Comment: I find the https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter  project to be quite useful. It also contains setup for testing, so it might be overkill for you if you are only playing.

Comment: yes ...So what is best way to debug the code ..because if there is an error ..than how I found

Comment: I did. I get the sourcemaps, and in chrome they are located under 'webpack://' in the sources directory in the dev-tools.

Comment: could you please tell me how to make hello world in angular 2 ..using webstrom and typscrict

Comment: i did not get ...files