# react, i18n, redux and react router configuration

Tags: reactjs, react-router, i18next, redux-framework

Ive got a simple (at the moment) app that uses react-router and redux and I would like to add internationalization functionality to it.

I have installed the npm package `react-i18next` and been able to install and run the example provided. I've added the appropriate imports into my own app and added the i18n tags to the root render method.

When I add the **I18nextProvider** tags to the render method, I get the error

> can't find module 'react'

Which is not particularly helpful, especially because if I remove the tags, the react app runs fine.

The render method that I am using is:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'    
....    

ReactDOM.render(
  <I18nextProvider i18n={ i18n }>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={DashboardIndex}/>
          <Route path="about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="collectors" component={Collectors}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
      <DevTools />
    </div>
  </Provider>
  </I18nextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
```

**Edit:**
I have started a blank application using a yo react generator, and it gives the same problem, so I can only assume this problem has something to do with the webpack build

I am very new to react/redux et al. but in the absence of lots of help on the internet would really appreciate any help.

The full stack trace is:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'o @
>   index.js?0f21:1(anonymous function) @ index.js?0f21:1r.4.react @
>   index.js?0f21:1o @ index.js?0f21:1(anonymous function) @ index.
>
> js?0f21:1r.2../I18nextProvider @ index.js?0f21:1o @ index.js?0f21:1e @
>   index.js?0f21:1(anonymous function) @ index.js?0f21:1c @
>   index.js?0f21:1(anonymous function) @ index.js?0f21:1(anonymous
>   function) @ app.js:4127__webpack_require__ @ app.js:535fn @
>   app.js:76(anonymous function) @ VM91841:35(anonymous function) @
>   index.js?9552:67(anonymous function) @ index.js?9552:67(anonymous
>   function) @ app.js:1024__webpack_require__ @ app.js:535fn @
>   app.js:76(anonymous function) @ app.js:567__webpack_require__ @
>   app.js:535(anonymous function) @ app.js:558(anonymous function) @
>   app.js:561
>       client?8a21:22 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.

Comment: Does your error come with a stack trace? That would help pinpoint exactly what's going wrong :)

Comment: added. I see some mentions of _webpack_require in there, but unsure of what this means

Comment: Ah, this isn't going to be particularly helpful unless you [enable source maps in webpack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31101665/801702). `__webpack_require__` is the function provided by webpack to replace `require`/`import` in your bundle, so it seems for some reason your i18n library is struggling to import React.

Comment: I've just taken a look at [react-i18next's dependencies](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/package.json#L23), and it looks like it doesn't include React. This is probably why webpack is failing to map it properly.

I'm gonna raise an issue on their github, and maybe a cheeky pull request to fix it.

Comment: Raised [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/10) and [accompanying PR](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/pull/11). If you wanna try my branch out, change your package.json to have `"react-i18next": "jimmed/react-i18next#patch-1"` instead of the current version, and run `npm i`.

Comment: Will have a look and see how I get on

Comment: @Jim I've hooked up your repo, but still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't ever get to the bottom of this problem from a technical perspective, so refactored to use `react-intl` for my internationalization needs instead. It works fine for me with `redux` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you require 'react' on that js file having the

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <I189nextProvider i18n={ i18n }>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <IndexRoute component={DashboardIndex}/>
          <Route path="about" component={About}/>
          <Route path="collectors" component={Collectors}/>
        </Route>
      </Router>
      <DevTools />
    </div>
  </Provider>
  </I189nextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
```

if not you have the problem...all your jsx gets converted to React.createComponent(...)

not requiring React will lead to a bundling error.

Comment: what you you mean by this?  I have a  `import React from 'react' ` statement - I mentioned in the OP

Comment: [This test suite seems to suggest otherwise](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/test/cases/concord/inner-modules-and-extensions/index.js). I could be wrong. The webpack codebase is insane.

Comment: yes..you need to import React from 'react' on top...see https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3Cdiv%20%2F%3E

that's what your code gets transpiled to. Using eg. eslint it would warn you about missing react.

Comment: Is it OK to use nested providers though?