# Console logging error on bundle.js instead of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have created a Webpack build which works fine for me - it has a dev-server which I use for hot-reloading, and a production express server that runs a template html file and integrates the `bundle.js` file.

This is all great, except when I'm working in my dev-server, the console gives me error messages like this:

`Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.(…) bundle.js:36329`

It references `bundle.js` as the source of the error, not the component I am working in, which makes it very difficult to track down the source of the error.

I know as far as the console is aware it is the `bundle.js` file that contains the error, but how can I get the console to log the pre-bundle code? (e.g. `Component.js`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It can't point you directly to the component since you're using the bundle. Better to do is add a break point to the line that causes the error and check from there

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should enable source mapping for a great debugging experience. Source map will link your bundle with your own code so when an error occurs, the error message will output the line number of your file, not the bundle. By default source map are disabled with webpack and can be enable with the property 'devtool' like this:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: '#eval-source-map',
    ...
};
```

Here's the link to the official documentation:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool

Comment: It would not let me correct my vote without editing the question

Answer (score 4):

**An easier approach to this is:**

> Goto Dev tools -> dev tools settings -> select "Preferences" tab ->
> select check box - "Enable JavaScript source maps"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    ...
    devtool: '#eval-source-map',
    ...
};
```

Adding this logs the error in the console with the actual component name and line number in the source. But this allows the users to view the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest webpack i.e v4 you need to write this

```
    // webpack.config.js
    module.exports = {
      ...
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      ...
    };
```

Updated Documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-source-maps

Comment: setting `mode: "development"` and `devtool: 'inline-source-map'` OR `devtool: 'source-map'` doesn't work for me - errors still reference extremely long lines in `bundle.js` which are highly minimised and obfuscated and i can't make sense of (using webpack `5.61.0`).

Comment: update:  for reference, in case it helps anyone else, i was using [UglifyJS Webpack Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin#sourcemap) - when i enabled `sourceMap: true` in that plugins configuration, i could see the source maps in chrome dev tools.  solution was inspired by this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41889062

Answer (score 1):

For webpack 6.0.1. I apply the following for logging in browser console:

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devtool: 'source-map',
  ...
}
```

To eliminate much logging and reduce bundle size in production mode you can use 'cheap-module-source-map':

```
//webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people using [craco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco),

You can achieve this by:

```
module.exports = {
    webpack: {
        configure: {
            // must be updated later for production optimization
            devtool: 'eval-source-map',
        },
    }
}
```