# Show file names instead of chunks in chrome developer console

Tags: reactjs, source-maps

When there is an error in my react 17 application, the chrome developer console shows errors to chunks file paths instead of the actual source file containing the component with error. Is it possible to show the real files path instead of chunks? I have checked and all of the files do have a source map generated for them.

**Sample error**

```
index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at tr
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1363:73
    at TableRow (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:42348:84)
    at thead
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:1363:73
    at TableHead (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:41463:84)
    at HeadTable (http://localhost:3000/static/js/4.chunk.js:504:21)
    at table
    ......
```

**Sample of desired result**

```
index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at tr
    at ./src/components/Table.tsx:1363:73
    ......
```

Comment: You are using CRA ?

Comment: Yes, so it could be nice to resolve this without doing `react-scripts eject`

Comment: If you do a fresh install of CRA into a new directory, do you still have this behavior? Have you added any advanced configuration to your CRA? On my end, with a fresh CRA, I see relative paths in Chrome dev tools for warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this section on React's Error Boundaries page: [Component Stack Traces](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3753)

It is a brief paragraph going over the result and instructions for using [this babel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source) to get the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

In development if you are using the [React Development Tool](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-devtools-extensions) in your Chrome Brower or Firefox you will be able to view the source code of your app and all its components.

If you want to see your React Redux state, I'd recommend [React Redux Development Tool](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) as well.

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify your webpack.config to enable source mapping, look at this post
[Console logging error on bundle.js instead of React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556547/console-logging-error-on-bundle-js-instead-of-react-component)