# How to see mapped files in console warnings with create-react-app / React 18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app

I recently upgraded React and several other packages to their latest versions, and every since, have been seeing warning messages in my Chrome console referring to bundled files instead of mapped files.

Example: `at SelectInput (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:119921:25)` instead of `at SelectInput (Select.tsx:123)`

I'm using the latest versions of chrome and React Devtools.

Here are my dependency versions in `package.json`:

```
dependencies {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@types/node": "^15.12.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
}
```

I see this older solution [Console logging error on bundle.js instead of React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40556547/console-logging-error-on-bundle-js-instead-of-react-component) but cannot find `webpack.config.js` to make updates, nor am I sure if it applies to these newer package updates.

How can I see the mapped file names in the chrome console?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that webpack is default installed in create-react-app.

And I found that  installing rewire allows at least to modify the webpack configuration.

That is not yet the full solution, but at least one step.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an "I'm having this problem too" post, or an actual answer? In case of the latter, please [edit] the answer to clarify how this would solve the problem. Otherwise, please delete this as the "post answer" button is only for actual answers, see [answer].

Comment: I edited to turn this into a contributed insight and input on overcoming one of the problems. This is technically a "partial answer". If however I misunderstood your post and you were asking for help with your problem, then please understand that you should use a question post for that. For most other things you can use your commenting privilege. Feel free to turn this into an answer according [answer], or add details and explanations to the partial answer, or to delete this.