# Errors started to point to the bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-dev-server, source-maps

For some reason, the error outputs for my React project now point to the bundle and not to my code:

[image]

Based on [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40560585/2725810), I added the `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
    devtool: '#eval-source-map',
};
```

This did not help.

My `.env`:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true
WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

I actually do see my source files in the development tools:

[image]

So it seems that the source maps exist, but are not used for some reason.

What could have gone wrong and how do I fix this?