React Native: debugging in chrome, no original source files available
I have a react-native application written in typescript which is bundled and deployed localy through webpack-dev-server.
I've been trying to debug the application in VSCode. I've successfully compiled and run the application, and I'm able to set breakpoints that are hit during application runtime. However, I'm running into an issue where the breakpoints in Chrome aren't synchronized with those in VSCode.
I've noticed that files that are supposed to be source code in Chrome appears to be the transpiled JavaScript, rather than the source TypeScript files (even though they have tsx extension). This discrepancy is causing the debugger to pause and display variables in completely different sections of the code than intended.


The application I'm trying to debug is open source project Expensify: https://github.com/Expensify/App. I'm relatively new to React, but when I created a simple MVP react-native project using webpack server and base libraries, everything worked fine and as expected. I also tried different source map settings in webpack server configuration but it didn't work.
I suspect the issue might be related to how the actual application is bundled and/or plugins used, but I'm not sure where to start looking. Any tips or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Sounds like a webpack issue. You might be out of luck.

@AustinPoulson, do you think it might be related to some babel plugins or some other webpack configuration? What is most likely you think?

I am not sure what the issue is, but here are some suggestions. 1: During development, compile without minification https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255380/can-i-get-webpack-to-bundle-but-without-minification-for-debugging. 2. In your tsconfig.json make sure sourceMap is set to true. Webpack often draws a lot of information from your tsconfig during the build process. You can also look into the official React devtools chrome extension (or separate server).
