# How do I debug transpiled javascript code?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using `Pycharm` to build an app in `ReactJS` and `webpack-dev-server` to serve the content. I see an error in my browser console and in order to debug, when I click on sources, I can only see the `<javascript_file>.min.js` and not my actual source code files. How do I go about debugging here?

Comment: What are you using to transpile your JS?

Comment: I'm using webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [enable sourcemaps in your webpack settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870830/how-do-i-generate-sourcemaps-when-using-babel-and-webpack), you'd be able to see the specific file when you are debugging.