# React-Dropzones + Webpacks throwing missing index.js.map error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dropzone

In my project, I want to use React-Dropzones for file uploading. Everything works fine, but when React-Dropzones is part of the project, its trying to pull an index.js.map file from my public javascripts folder (and this file doesnt exist).

I'm using Webpacks with the following config:

```
{
      entry: './app/js/' + file,
      output: { 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/javascripts_react'), 
        filename: file.replace(".js", "") + mode + ".js" },
      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      node: {
        fs: "empty",
        module: "empty"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can ignore that.

Map files are used to make minified CSS and JS files readable by adding the source line numbers to the minified code. Whenever you have minified code, and open the browser developer console, the browser will try to download the map file. If it can't - you will see the minifed js/css without line numbers.

Keep in mind that as long as you don't open the console, the browser will not try to download the minified file.

you can read [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) more about minified files, or find out how to [add js maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870830/how-do-i-generate-sourcemaps-when-using-babel-and-webpack) using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html).