# what's the difference using eval and eval-source-map?

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to config the source map. I am wondering anyone could clarify the difference between "eval" and "eval-source-map" ? I don't see the difference personally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/):

> **eval** - Each module is executed with eval() and //@ sourceURL. This is
>   pretty fast. The main disadvantage is that it doesn't display line
>   numbers correctly since it gets mapped to transpiled code instead of
>   the original code (No Source Maps from Loaders).
>
> **eval-source-map** - Each module is executed with eval() and a SourceMap
>   is added as a DataUrl to the eval(). Initially it is slow, but it
>   provides fast rebuild speed and yields real files. Line numbers are
>   correctly mapped since it gets mapped to the original code. It yields
>   the best quality SourceMaps for development.

Essentially `eval-source-map` is slower, but has more accurate mapping to the original line numbers (helpful for identifying the appropriate lines of bugs in the original source code).

Comment: why eval-source-map has fater rebuild speed?