# Reactjs Source map

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have added `.env` file in my react project that means when project uploads in the server in console source showing all components.

I got to add `.env` that file I worte

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = false;
```

but Still it's showing all components in source can any one help me out?

Thanks adv

Comment: You should ideally be using webpack config for source map changes. 
Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870830/how-do-i-generate-sourcemaps-when-using-babel-and-webpack

Comment: @kiran, I think you should delete .map file before code push to server using script. I usually use rimraf package to remove all .map files. I used this script "postbuild": "rimraf build/**/*.map" to remove my script after code build process done.

Comment: Note: [It is recommended to leave source maps in your builds.](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/866039084573233152)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the semicolon:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

[Under the hood](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/69c3d4b04c233ba9fb9d16691056bd09076177b1/packages/react-scripts/config/env.js), [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules) is used to read `.env` files.