# App list in React developer tool extension for Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a ReactJS web application using Chrome developer tools and the React developer tools extension, as described in [this answer posted by Elia Weiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516580/debugging-jsx-using-browser-plugins).  The React tab (1) appears for me as described, but the App list folder (2) in the Source tab does not.

Is there some additional React configuration needed to make the App list appear?

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: If you are using webpack, then you might find reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42254164/4248342) answer helpful.

Comment: I am using webpack, and did add devtool: 'source-map' to module.exports in webpack.config.js.  Still no app list.  Have you succeeded in getting the app list to display?

Comment: Frankly speaking, I've never tried that, whenever I need to debug/analyze any file. I just press `Ctrl + P` to open quick file search and I can directly go to file.

Comment: I also tried Ctrl+P, but my JSX source files are not listed, just app.js

Comment: Can you try `eval-source-map` and/or switching the browser? In the past chrome had some issues which were creating problems when working with source-map. Also, if you have hot reloading on, can you try disabling it and see if it works. Which webpack, chrome version you are using?