# debug jsx file in chrome, is it possible

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

How can I debug jsx in chrome? (using webpack.config & react.js)
Im using chrome extension for react and I can see the components I created 
but can debug only the output js file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging JSX using browser / plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27516580/debugging-jsx-using-browser-plugins)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because they changed the chrome plugin, and now it doesn't behave the way indicated in the above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found something by using transform-react-jsx  and add it to babelrc
im reciveing jsx files in chrome , to exactly the code i wrote but can use it to debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use JS ***debugger*** for this one.

debugger; - when the parser encounters this directive, and the Developer Tools are open it will trigger a breakpoint.

Comment: not work, i can debug the js output after the transpiler work